# Why does my 2D-array initialize with a random integer value at index 0 after using calloc()?

Tags: c, memory, compiler-errors

At school I need to make an assignment in which I use a 2-Dimensional array.
There is a goal value that is given as input, which determines the amount of elements in the array's first dimension. 
The second dimension is an operation that we do on the current element and how much it would theoretically cost us to do.

For some reason my value at [0][0] in the array changes to a random integer value after I initialize it with calloc() (Which would set the array to 0).

We use a 2D-array to store the optimal mathematical operation to perform to get to our goal value together with the theoretical cost of that operation.

```
typedef struct GoalArray {
  int **path;    /* 2D-Array of operations and cost for each element */
} GoalArray;


  GoalArray makeGoalArray(int goal) {
  /* Returns an empty 2-Dimenional GoalArray.
   * Due to there being 6 limited mathematical operations, our maximal 
   * needed index in the array is: (3 * the goal value) + 1.
   */

  printf("Goal : %d", goal);

  GoalArray ga;
  ga.path = calloc((goal * 3) + 1, sizeof(int));
  assert(ga.path != NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i < (goal * 3) + 1; i++){
    ga.path[i] = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
    assert(ga.path[i] != NULL);
    printf("i = %d:  %d, %d\n", i, ga.path[i][0], ga.path[i][1]);
  }

  printf("\nTest %d, %d\n", ga.path[0][0], ga.path[0][1]);
  return ga;
}
```

With a goal of 2 it produces this output:

```
Goal : 2
i = 0:  0, 0
i = 1:  0, 0
i = 2:  0, 0
i = 3:  0, 0
i = 4:  0, 0
i = 5:  0, 0
i = 6:  0, 0

Test 19244512, 0
```

How is it possible that in the print-statement of test the value of the array at index [0][0] has changed?

Comment: `ga.path = calloc((goal * 3) + 1, sizeof(int));` ->  `ga.path = calloc((goal * 3) + 1, sizeof(int*));` (note the `*`)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you so, so much. It fixed my problem indeed.

Comment: Further, `goal` is not even used in the inner-dimension of the allocation strategy. The inner-most size s completely fixed (two `int` values). That means an `int (*path)[2]` could be used and this nesting of pointers to pointer to int could be completely thrown out.

Comment: Do you understand why it was a problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right, that would be even better. Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneSh. To be honest, I don't know how many bytes a pointer to an int would be, but I know that an int is 4 bytes. How it could result to the random integer value is a mystery to me.

Comment: In C an `int` must be at least 16 bits (you corrected "4 bits").

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I mixed them up first, my bad.

Comment: `ga.path = calloc((goal * 3) + 1, sizeof(int*));` can be coded better as `ga.path = calloc((goal * 3) + 1, sizeof *ga.path);`.  No need to code the type  - and get it wrong.  Easier to review and maintain.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I didn't know that was possible. I love how programming keeps surprising me with new stuff there is to learn.